# android help! pagetabstrip, title adapter, inflater and viewpager all unknown classes

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I'm trying to build a tabbed layout on android, I've coded it but its telling me that the title adapter, view pager variable and activity main inflated in oncreateoptionsmenu is unknown classes, I'm totally stuck and any help would be grateful.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (pagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pagerTabStrip);

        TitleAdapter titleAdapter = new    TitleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(TitleAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.Activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: To save us some time, what solutions have you tried?

Comment: post the code for `TitleAdapter`

Comment: ive added it as an answer below @FabinPaul

Comment: ive tried using actionbar but it is now deprecated in android studio 1.5 @Knells

Comment: what is the package name for `TitleAdapter`? have imported it in `MainActivity`?